# How to get the index of targeted element in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, indexing, foreach

I'm trying to get the index of targeted element inside of the `forEach - addEventListener` method. But it is not easy to get those as I thought before.

```js
  let contents = document.querySelectorAll('.contents');
  let table = document.querySelectorAll('.table');
  function eventRegister() {
    contents.forEach((items, idx) => {
      items.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
        console.log(items[idx]);
        console.log(event.target[idx]);
        console.log(event.currentTarget[idx]);
        console.log(items.index);
        console.log(event.target.index);
        console.log(event.currentTarget.index); // all of those console.log is firing undefined
        if (idx > 4) {
          table.classList.remove('shown');
        } else {
          table.classList.add('shown');
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

```css
.shown {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="contents">this</div>
  <div class="contents">is</div>
  <div class="contents">a</div>
  <div class="contents">text</div>
  <div class="contents">group</div>
  <div class="contents">test</div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="things">a</div>
  <div class="things">b</div>
  <div class="things">c</div>
  <div class="things">d</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to get the index each of the elements from `contents` and if its index is greater than 4, remove the class `shown` from `table`.

Are there any ways to get the index each of the targeted elements in `forEach` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether `idx` is greater than 4:

```js
let contents = document.querySelectorAll('.contents');
let table = document.querySelector('.table');

function eventRegister() {
  contents.forEach((item, idx) => {
    item.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      if (idx > 4) {
        table.classList.remove('shown');
      } else {
        table.classList.add('shown');
      }
    });
  });
}

eventRegister();
```

```css
.shown {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="contents">this</div>
  <div class="contents">is</div>
  <div class="contents">a</div>
  <div class="contents">text</div>
  <div class="contents">group</div>
  <div class="contents">test</div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="things">a</div>
  <div class="things">b</div>
  <div class="things">c</div>
  <div class="things">d</div>
</div>
```

Note that the first parameter of `forEach` is the current element being iterated over, so you should probably call it `item`, not `items`, to avoid confusing yourself. (It's not a collection, it's a single element.)

You could also use event delegation, instead of adding lots of individual listeners:

```js
let contents = document.querySelectorAll('.contents');
let table = document.querySelector('.table');

function eventRegister() {
  const box = document.querySelector('.box');
  box.addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => {
    if (!target.matches('.contents')) {
      return;
    }
    const index = [...box.children].indexOf(target);
    if (index > 4) {
      table.classList.remove('shown');
    } else {
      table.classList.add('shown');
    }
  });
}

eventRegister();
```

```css
.shown {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="contents">this</div>
  <div class="contents">is</div>
  <div class="contents">a</div>
  <div class="contents">text</div>
  <div class="contents">group</div>
  <div class="contents">test</div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="things">a</div>
  <div class="things">b</div>
  <div class="things">c</div>
  <div class="things">d</div>
</div>
```